# Iterate through a column in a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am doing questionnaire on php, I am new to php. When I try to show the answers, it only shows the first two questions. After the two questions, answers are not shown. I have attached the source here.

Please use the following link to view the page.
http://itsupportsrilanka.com/uaquiz/quiz.php

```
<body>

<form action="test.php" method="POST">


   <?php
            $result = select("SELECT * FROM questions ");
            //$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


        ?>
<?php
$i=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<table width="581" height="299" border="1">
<tr>
<td>Union Assurance Questionnaire</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $i.'.' .$row['questions']; ?>
<?php $i++; ?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<?php $qId=$row['question_id'];

$result1=select("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE questionId='$qId' ORDER BY RAND()");
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){

    ?>
    <input type="radio" name="answers" value="<?php echo $row1['answers'];?>" / ><?php echo $row1['answers']; ?><br/>


<?php 
} ?>
&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
</form>
</body>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: my suggestion would be stop using mysql functions learn PDO...

Comment: can you paste your question & answers table structure ?

Comment: do one thing for debuggin ? echo your answer as text in p tag without radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$result = select("SELECT * FROM questions "); with $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions ");
```

and

```
$result1=select("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE questionId='$qId' ORDER BY RAND()"); with 
$result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE questionId='$qId' ORDER BY RAND()");
```

and try again

Comment: have you tried mysql_query or mysqli_query? I have refreshed the link given by you and it shows error for mysqli_query. I have suggested mysql_query.Your table structure shows answers for question id 1 and 2 only, are there more records?

Comment: sorry to all this is my mistake, I didn't have more records in my table. thanks pkachhia.., your comments is very usefull for me.